# Extract and assign selected rows of structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, struct, cell

```
S.a=rand(100,3)
S.b=rand(100,3)
S.c=rand(100,3)
S.d=rand(100,3)

K.a=[ ]
K.b=[ ]
K.c=[ ]
K.d=[ ]

for i=1:numel(S)
   if rand<0.8   % condition
      K(i,:)=S(i,:) % How this assignment can be made
   end
end
```

How to extract the rows of all the fields of a structure and store it to another structure.

Comment: How do you mean "rows of structure"? A structure has fields, not rows. A field may have rows, or may contain another structure, a scalar, a cell or what have you. Please [edit] the question to clarify, preferably with sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure from you explanation if this is what you want. The following code will copy the fields from in S into K for just the rows where the items are < 0.8

```
S.a=rand(100,3);
S.b=rand(100,3);
S.c=rand(100,3);
S.d=rand(100,3);
K = [];

for field = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    I = rand(length(S.(field)), 1) < 0.8;
    K.(field) = S.(field)(I,:);
end
```

Comment: rand<0.8 is not a fieldvalue but probability condition to randomly select rows
 of all the fields.
So, 'I' variable may not appear.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want. I modified my answer.